# Uploading a text file in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web page on which users can upload text files (but a text file, i.e. a file with the extension .txt, could be of many encodings, e.g. ASCII, UTF8, UNICODE .. etc), I'm trying to validate the contents in memory before I save the file to the disk, if the content is not valid, I don't save the file. I'm reading the content from the file upload control (fileUpload1.FileContent which returns a stream of bytes), is there an easy way in .NET to convert the content of the uploaded file to a string (i.e. the byte stream returned from fileUpload1.FileContent) or will I have to check the first bytes to detect the encoding first?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can do this:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileUpload1.FileContent);
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Example of text file format

Code#Name#Fathername#DOB#Location#MobileNo
1#XYZ#YYY#09-06-89#LKO#9999999999



     protected void btnUpload_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsValid)
            {
                bool logval = true;
                if (logval == true)
                {
                    if (fuUploadExcelName.HasFile)
                    {
                        String img_1 = fuUploadExcelName.PostedFile.FileName;
                        String img_2 = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(img_1);
                        string extn = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(img_1);
                        string frstfilenamepart = "Text" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");/*Filename for storing in Desired path*/
                        UploadExcelName.Value = frstfilenamepart + extn;
                        fuUploadExcelName.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Text/") + "/" + UploadExcelName.Value);/*Uploaded text file will be store at this path*/

                        string filename = UploadExcelName.Value;
                        string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Text/" + filename);




                        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filePath);
                        string[] ColumnNames = file.ReadLine().Split('#');/*read data from textfile*/
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        foreach (string Column in ColumnNames)
                        {
                            dt.Columns.Add(Column);/*adding the columns/
                        }
                        string NewLine;
                        while ((NewLine = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                            string[] values = NewLine.Split('#');

                            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                            {
                                dr[i] = values[i].TrimEnd();
                            }
                            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                        }
                        file.Close();
                        grdview.DataSource = dt;/*make datasouce from text file*
                        grdview.DataBind();/*binding the grid*/


                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.